# ShareButton in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, twitter, social-networking

guys. I have a problem. I maked three share buttons (fb , tw, tumblr) in wp but they render title and description with my home page in social networks. 
i do not now why this is true. I used sdk fb , link parameters and , but title and description and etc get with home page.
htts/"link-home-page"/"site-with-share-button"/

Comment: are you using a plugin ?

Comment: No i do not use. I am using links parameters and <meta> from official sites fb, tw, tumblr

Comment: i advice you to use plugin . See the best social plugin here : 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/best-social-media-plugins-for-wordpress/

Comment: _“I have a problem”_ - please go read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Try to use plugin which is time consumption

Refer this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-media-feather/

may be helpful to share your post without any issue regards your type